# transform char to numeric data in mutate assign to data frame variable

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, case-when

Problem context: replace a chr variable in data frame by retaining the chr values in data frame using mutate case_when to conditionally inspect (case_when) to determine value for mutated result.

The target is a variable named: length_of_service

conditional data for case_when is:
"< 1 year", "2 years", "3 years", "4 years", "5 years", "6 years", "7 years", "8 years", "9 years", "10+ years"

Attempted effort code: I can build a data frame with one variable, length_of_service, transform the character string of year(s) to an equivalent numeric, then mutate the variable inside this data frame, then cbind() the df_length data frame with the original data frame. I do not wish to overwrite the original length_of_services inside the original data frame until the mutate / case_when() clause is executed. Then I can replace with the cbind() to combine data frames. I welcome suggestions to problem approach solution.

```
df_length <- data.frame(length_of_service = numeric())
df_length %>% 
   mutate(df$length_of_service == case_when(
          df$length_of_service == "< 1 year" ~ 0.99,
          df$length_of_service == "2 years" ~ 2,
          df$length_of_service == "3 years" ~ 3,
          df$length_of_service == "4 years" ~ 4,
          df$length_of_service == "5 years" ~ 5,
          df$length_of_service == "6 years" ~ 6,
          df$length_of_service == "7 years" ~ 7,
          df$length_of_service == "8 years" ~ 8,
          df$length_of_service == "9 years" ~ 9,
          df$length_of_service == "10+ years" ~ 10,
          TRUE ~ "NA"
   )
```

Result / Error:

Error: must be a double vector, not a character vector

Comment: You say *I do not wish to overwrite the original length_of_services inside the original data frame until the mutate / case_when() clause is executed.*. The variable will be updated with the new numeric values after it evaluates your `case_when` so I am not sure what your problem is here. In any case, you can create a new variable in the same data frame IF you do not want to overwrite the existing one...

Answer (score 0):

`case_when` expects value to be returned of same type so return `NA_real` instead of `"NA"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(length_of_service_new = case_when(
             length_of_service == "< 1 year" ~ 0.99,
             length_of_service == "2 years" ~ 2,
             length_of_service == "3 years" ~ 3,
             length_of_service == "4 years" ~ 4,
             length_of_service == "5 years" ~ 5,
             length_of_service == "6 years" ~ 6,
             length_of_service == "7 years" ~ 7,
             length_of_service == "8 years" ~ 8,
             length_of_service == "9 years" ~ 9,
             length_of_service == "10+ years" ~ 10,
             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

---

I would however do,

```
df %>% 
 mutate(year = readr::parse_number(length_of_service),
        length_of_service_new = replace(year, year == 1, 0.99))
```

which should return the same output as the above `case_when` output.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
years <-
  as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]|[[:punct:]]|\\s+", "", df$length_of_service))

df$length_of_service_new <-
  ifelse(years == 1, .99, ifelse(years > 10, 10, years))

# Data:

df <- data.frame(
  length_of_service =
    c(
      "< 1 year",
      "2 years",
      "3 years",
      "4 years",
      "5 years",
      "6 years",
      "7 years",
      "8 years",
      "9 years",
      "10+ years",
      "11 years"
    )
)
```